# Way to implement a callback into a .attr in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm working with canvas and images. In certain point of my flow, I have to set the `src` attribute of a image:

```
$("#image").attr("src", "something");
```

And then I do some processing that implies messing up with the image. But if I don't put an `alert()` between the `.attr()` and the call of the next line, it doesn't work. With the alert it works just fine. I had to call a `setTimeout()` in order to give some time to the `.attr()` to finish.

`$().load` doesn't work because the image is loaded, the src of the image is changed with a click. So, is there a way to implement a callback in `.attr()`? If there is not such way, which could be the better way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try replacing the dom node with a new node using `.replace()` and then attach the `.load()` event. I haven't tried it but it might work.

Comment: You really should not be setting the "src" attribute with ".attr()" - it might not work at all in IE.  Use ".prop()" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a preloading technique:

```
var imagePreloader = $("<img />").attr("src", "something");
imagePreloader.bind('load', function(){

    // image has been loaded in your browser cache, now you can
    // change the source of your real image
    $("#image").prop("src", "something");

});
```

Comment: As I said in a comment on the question, since jQuery 1.6 you should really use ".prop()" to set properties like "src".

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace the image with a new image, rather than changing its source?